# How do you write to files with the build action "Content"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a file in my solution called "Voicecmd.xml" and need to write to it programically. How do I do that?

Code used to update/edit voicecmd and where i'm stuck...

```
async void updateall()
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("voicecmd.xml");
    var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.0");
    texb.Text = xDoc.Root.Element(ns + "CommandSet").Element(ns + "CommandPrefix").Value;
}

    private async void ttcc(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("voicecmd.xml");
        var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.0");
        xDoc.Root.Element(ns + "CommandSet").Element(ns + "CommandPrefix").Value = texb.Text;
        // xDoc.Save(StreamWriter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can write to even project file. Here's a [link](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html).

Otherwise you can always copy it to `IsolatedStorage` and write to it.

Comment: That file is talking about win8/rt. I need WP8.

Comment: It seems to be. When editing the code, the only thing that was not found was Windows.Storage.FileIO.

Comment: Also, about copying to IsolatedStorage, I would need to copy it back to Content when done editing. I don't think that is possible from what I have tried...

Comment: Why would you need to copy it back to content? You can just keep it in the storage and use it as needed.

Comment: The file is for the Windows Phone speech recognition API. Therefore, it needs to be set as content and accessed via URI from what I know. The reason i'm editing the file is to allow the user to change the prefix used before saying a speech command. I have the code done and working, but got stuck trying to save to the proper location.

Comment: This is the code I use to load up the speech XML files:             VoiceCommandService.InstallCommandSetsFromFileAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///voicecmd.xml"));